# How to include a python function in the source of html iframe?

Tags: python, html, function, ip

how i put a function from python file to the iframe source of html file ?

**html file:**

```
<iframe src='http://192.168.1.100/' id="gallery" class="iframe" name='gallery' width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" seamless="seamless" align="left"></iframe>
```

in the src='...' i want to use the function: interact().GetInIP() and the http:// protocol. I have try this:

```
<iframe src= 'http://' + interact().GetInIP() + '/'
```

and also with parenthesis 
but didn't works...

This is my function **GetInIP()** in class: **interact()** which i use to take  automatic the ip address of raspberry pi:

```
def GetInIP(self):
  output = check_output(["ip","addr","show","wlan0"])
  inIP = output.split('\n')[2].strip().split(' ')[1].split('/')[0]
  return inIP
```

the reason i want to do this is to avoid to change the ip address every time i connect the RPi to another network.

Comment: Can you serve the html with something like flask? Then you could modify the templates in the html: https://stackabuse.com/serving-static-files-with-flask/

Answer (score 0):

Python unfortunately cannot run natively in the browser so this is not possible, you can only use JavaScript.

Comment: how i do it with javascript?

Comment: You can't interface with your Raspberry Pi while in the browser. You will have to run some sort of server implementation such as Flask which @stradivari suggested.